# ORDER BY with WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I can't seem to get ORDER BY to work with my current MySQL Query I'm using!

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE game_platform = '$gameType' ORDER BY ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I just get the following error.

Warning:

> mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in

Comment: Your problem is not so dramatic that it requires a `!`. You lack error handling on your query and have assumed it worked properly.

Comment: `echo $query` and see what sql gets to database - probably syntax error, invalid `$gametype` value

Answer (score 10):

`ORDER BY` what??

You didn't specify what column to order by. You have to specify the order columns. Something like so.

```
 ORDER BY somefield ASC
```

However, if you have a column called `ASC` in your table and you want to order by it, you have to escape it like so:

```
ORDER BY `ASC`
```

Since `ASC` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

```
      Please enter colname :

  $query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE game_platform = '" . $gameType .
     "' ORDER BY colname ASC ";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE game_platform = '$gameType' ORDER BY game_platform ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html